# How to configure metricbeat helm chart to output to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, metricbeat

I'm trying to install metricbeat helm chart to forward my kubernetes metrics to elasticsearch.

Default configuration works but when I configure output to elasticsearch, the pod tell me

> > Exiting: error unpacking config data: more than one namespace configured accessing 'output' (source:'metricbeat.yml')

I download the [values.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/metricbeat/values.yaml) and modify output.file in both daemonset and deployment from

```
output.file:
  path: "/usr/share/metricbeat/data"
  filename: metricbeat
  rotate_every_kb: 10000
  number_of_files: 5
```

to

```
output.file:
  enable: false
output.elasticsearch:
  enable: true
  hosts: ["http://192.168.10.156:9200/"]
```

How do I modify the config to forward metrics to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the fine manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/6.x/file-output.html#_literal_enabled_literal_6), the property is actually `enabled:` not `enable:` so I would presume you actually want:

```
output.file:
  enabled: false
```

Although to be honest, I always thought you could have as many outputs as you wish, but [that is clearly not true](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/more-than-one-namespace-configured-accessing-output/146646)